# Shows / symbol before the zip file name in uwp

Tags: uwp

I am currently working on UWP project.I want to zip files inside a folder.I am using following code to do that task

```
public async Task ToCSV()
    {

        var localRoot = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path;
        if (dataStore.getCurrentClassroomId() != null)
        {
            currentClassroomId = dataStore.getCurrentClassroomId();
        }
        else
        {
            //do nothing
        }

        //create classroomdata folder in local state folder
        DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(localRoot +"\\" +currentClassroomId+ "\\ClassroomData");
        if (!d.Exists)
            d.Create();
        StorageFolder classroomdataFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(localRoot + "\\" + currentClassroomId + "\\ClassroomData");

        //create .csv files inside classroomdata folder 
        StorageFile classroomFile = await classroomdataFolder.CreateFileAsync( "classroom.csv", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        StorageFile classroomcourselogFile = await classroomdataFolder.CreateFileAsync("classroomcourselog.csv", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        StorageFile classroomcoursemapFile = await classroomdataFolder.CreateFileAsync("classroomcoursemap.csv", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        StorageFile classroomdataFile = await classroomdataFolder.CreateFileAsync("classroomdata.csv", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        StorageFile classroomlogFile = await classroomdataFolder.CreateFileAsync("classroomlog.csv", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        StorageFile classroomteamFile = await classroomdataFolder.CreateFileAsync("classroomteam.csv", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        StorageFile classroomtopiccontentlogFile = await classroomdataFolder.CreateFileAsync("classroomtopiccontentlog.csv", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        StorageFile classroomtopiccontentmapFile = await classroomdataFolder.CreateFileAsync("classroomtopiccontentmap.csv", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        StorageFile classroomtopiclogFile = await classroomdataFolder.CreateFileAsync("classroomtopiclog.csv", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        StorageFile classroomtopicmapFile = await classroomdataFolder.CreateFileAsync("classroomtopicmap.csv", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        //create zip file of csv files
       if (classroomdataFolder != null)
         {              
            StorageFile zipFile = await classroomdataFolder.CreateFileAsync(currentClassroomId+".zip", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            Stream zipToCreate = await zipFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();
            ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipToCreate, ZipArchiveMode.Update);

            await ZipFolderContentsHelper(classroomdataFolder, archive, classroomdataFolder.Path);
            archive.Dispose();

        }

     }


private async Task ZipFolderContentsHelper(StorageFolder sourceFolder, ZipArchive archive, string sourceFolderPath)
    {
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await sourceFolder.GetFilesAsync();

        foreach (StorageFile file in files)
        {
            ZipArchiveEntry readmeEntry = archive.CreateEntry(file.Path.Remove(0, sourceFolderPath.Length));
            ulong fileSize = (await file.GetBasicPropertiesAsync()).Size;
            byte[] buffer = fileSize > 0 ? WindowsRuntimeBufferExtensions.ToArray(await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file)) : new byte[0];
            using (Stream entryStream = readmeEntry.Open())
            {
                await entryStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
        }

        IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> subFolders = await sourceFolder.GetFoldersAsync();

        if (subFolders.Count() == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (StorageFolder subfolder in subFolders)
        {
            await ZipFolderContentsHelper(subfolder, archive, sourceFolderPath);
        }
    }
```

It create the Zip file.But the issue is it shows "/" symbol before zip name and file's name.I cannot understand where the this error comes from.I would appreciate if anyone can help me to resolve this issue.
[This is the screen shot of Zip file I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6YBf.png)

Comment: Have you tried unzip the file and the sub file name also contains "/" ?

Comment: yes I did.Then it doesn't show / before names.I want to use this zip file to import to a database and zip file needs to have defined name(currentclassroomid).The issue is it gives error saying there is / before zip name when i try to import it.

Comment: I have reply the answer please check the following.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shows / symbol before the zip file name in uwp

The problem is that `readmeEntry` name is not correct. you could try use this to replace the default one.

```
ZipArchiveEntry readmeEntry = archive.CreateEntry(file.Path.Remove(0, sourceFolderPath.Length+1));
```